# Installing Zorba (XQUERY) PHP Extension on Windows

Tags: php, xml, xquery, pecl, zorba

I'm trying to install zorba php extension on windows and I am having all sorts of problems. I have installed the zorba binaries on my computer, but when I try to install the PECL package (pecl install zorba-alpha) I get the following error `"ERROR: the DSP zorba.dsp does not exist"`.

I've tried searching for `zorba_api.dll` or `zorba_api.so` in order to just bypass the pecl install process, but no luck.

If anyone can tell me how to get the zorba extension installed on my windows php I will be eternally grateful. Alternately, if someone knows of another xquery solution for PHP that I can install, I will be equally excited and appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following resource will help you: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1487285/php/php.html

Please let me know if it works.